# Editor stuck when using getValue or setValue in Vue3 reference object

Tags: vuejs3, monaco-editor

When I use monaco-editor in Vue3, the editor will stuck when I call getValue or setValue on reactive object of editor.

If I don't call getValue or setValue, the editor works fine, but I can't get the value of the editor.

```html
<template>
  <div class="editor" ref="editorRef"></div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'

const code = ref('')
const editorRef = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
const editor = ref<monaco.editor.IStandaloneCodeEditor | null>(null)

onMounted(() => {
  editor.value = monaco.editor.create(editorRef.value!, {
    value: code.value,
    language: 'javascript'
  })

  editor.value.getModel()?.onDidChangeContent(() => (code.value = editor.value?.getValue() || ''))
})
</script>
```

I tried to use the toRaw API provided by Vue3 to get the raw object from the reference object, luckily it worked!

```
const originEditor = toRaw(editor)
originEditor.getValue() // 'Hello, World!'
orifinEditor.setValue('Hello, Monaco!') // success
```

I would like to know what is the difference between these two ways:

```
editor.value.getValue() // editor stucked
originEditor.getValue() // work well
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make the editor reactive. There is not sense in doing this.

And I would commonly recommend to make reactive only things that really need to be reactive. Especially big and complex objects could be broken when they are proxied by Vue Reactivity.

You can define your editor as simple variable

```
let editor = null;
```

If it will not work with the variable, then try a computed property with a `getter` and `setter`

```
let _editor = null;
const editor = computed({
  get() {
    return _editor
  },
  set(val) {
    _editor = val
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still don't quite understand this sentence: `Especially big and complex objects could be broken when they are proxied by Vue Reactivity.`, what operations are done inside Vue after calling `getValue` on the Ref object? What caused the UI rendering to get stuck? I found a similar question in the project's Github repository discussion area, but it didn't seem to answer the difference between the two. Maybe you need to find the answer to this question from the monaco source level: [monaco-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/discussions/3800)